# The use of "over-" as an excess term (as in "overzealous")

Tags: prepositions, compound-adjectives, compound-words

Is the word "overzealous" only used in a negative sense? Because I understand that "over-exaggerate" is used in a negative way due to it's double-excessive use. Would that mean any excessive term accompanied by "over" is said to be in a negative way?

Comment: What did your dictionary say about it?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's inherently negative but it does, I think, imply excessive excessiveness, if you will.  And, yes, in many cases that can be seen as negative.

Comment: If you are overpaid in your job is that negative or positive?

Comment: @Jim depends on your perspective.  It's not good for the company.  And if you're the employee, you probably wouldn't use the word "overpaid," unless you were ridiculing the company for paying you more than even you think you deserve.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime - Exactly my point.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in these cases, the word **over** is using [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over) from Merriam-Webster:

> a (1) :  beyond some quantity, limit, or norm often by a specified amount or to a specified degree show ran a minute over (2) :  in an excessive manner :  inordinately

As the definition implies, it does mean that something is done **beyond** what is necessary.  It is **excessive**.

In most contexts, that would have a negative connotation.  Doing something beyond the norm or need could certainly be perceived as a negative trait of the action.

Comment: Very true -- a good, simple answer!  'Over' carries the same meaning as 'too' in these cases, reminding us of the old saying 'too much of anything is a bad thing'!